# How can i use a script to feed another script settings?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The first script is attached to a empty GameObject.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class SpinableObject
{
    public Transform t;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public float minSpeed;
    public float maxSpeed;
    public float speedRate;
    public bool slowDown;
}
public class SpinObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SpinableObject[] objectsToRotate;
    private Rotate _rotate;
    private int index = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        _rotate = new Rotate>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var _objecttorotate = objectsToRotate[index];
        _rotate.rotationSpeed = _objecttorotate.rotationSpeed;
        _rotate.minSpeed = _objecttorotate.minSpeed;
        _rotate.maxSpeed = _objecttorotate.maxSpeed;
        _rotate.speedRate = _objecttorotate.speedRate;
        _rotate.slowDown = _objecttorotate.slowDown;
    }
}
```

The second script is attached to the GameObject/s i want to feed with information. So this script is attached to each GameObject separate.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public float minSpeed;
    public float maxSpeed;
    public float speedRate;
    public bool slowDown;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        RotateObject();
    }

    public void RotateObject()
    {
        if (rotationSpeed > maxSpeed)
            slowDown = true;
        else if (rotationSpeed < minSpeed)
            slowDown = false;

        rotationSpeed = (slowDown) ? rotationSpeed - 0.1f : rotationSpeed + 0.1f;
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
    }
}
```

Not sure if this is a good way to what i want to do ?

Second problem is that the variable _rotate in the first script is all the time null:

I'm doing:

```
_rotate = new Rotate>();
```

But still here it's null:

```
_rotate.rotationSpeed = _objecttorotate.rotationSpeed;
```

Comment: @daniel-lee : You have been on StackOverflow for 10 days and you have posted 11 questions. It seems you are asking the community to do all the job for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you understand how Unity works.

First, `_rotate = new Rotate>();` is not valid C# and will throw an error.

Second, in your case `Rotate` is a `MonoBehaviour` which is not attached to a `GameObject`. I think that whatever you tried to accomplish is maybe a step to far. You can' synchronize the `Update`-call of a deattached `Component` (of which I don't even know if it gets its `Update`-method called) with another object at all. In short: Your code seems nonsense to me.

I'd suggest, you move your `RotateObject` method into the `SpinableObject` and call it from `SpinObject`, instead of shoving stuff into `_rotate`. This should work.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class SpinableObject
{
    public Transform t;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public float minSpeed;
    public float maxSpeed;
    public float speedRate;
    public bool slowDown;

    public void RotateObject()
    {
        if (rotationSpeed > maxSpeed)
            slowDown = true;
        else if (rotationSpeed < minSpeed)
            slowDown = false;

        rotationSpeed = (slowDown) ? rotationSpeed - 0.1f : rotationSpeed + 0.1f;
        t.Rotate(Vector3.forward, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
    }
}
public class SpinObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private SpinableObject[] objectsToRotate;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        foreach(var spinner in objectsToRotate)
            spinner.RotateObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working. And if i want to add some global variables ? I mean that the variables now will effect each transform alone but the global variables will effect all the transforms. If in the array for example there are 5 objects so if i will use the global variables it will effect on all the 5 gameobjects at the same time and if not using the global variable each gameobject in the array will use his own variables. Maybe using some bool like: globalEffect ?

Comment: Add the "global" variables to your `SpinObject`, and pass the values to `RotateObject()`.